# How to set cwd in VSCode Ipython?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, spyder

I'm migrating from Spyder to VSCode and would like to use it in a similar way.

One of the major problems I'm facing is to set de cwd to the folder of the file I'm working. There is a lot of question just like mine in the Google, but none of them solved my problem.

Here are my configs:

```
"code-runner.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
 "code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
 "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
 "python.testing.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
 "python.terminal.launchArgs": [
 "-m",
 "IPython"
    ],
 "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
 "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": false
```

**What I want to do is to execute my file in IPython with the cwd setted to my file directory, to load some CSVs that are in the file folder, also be able to run some independent lines or enter some code directly in Ipython with all the variables loaded.**

I don't want to just RUN the file or DEBUG, because I want to prototype some lines of code right in the IPython console with all the variables loaded.

With my configs, what I usually do is to select all the lines of the script and CTRL + ENTER. This will open a terminal with Ipython but setted to my project folder, not my file folder.

If I open a REPL, I get the same problem: Ipython opened but not set to file folder. Worse I can't use the CTRL + Enter to send some independent lines to Ipython (in this situation CTRL + Enter will cause to open a new terminal)

If I open a terminal by the Terminal menu, the console is setted to my file folder, but without python.

The closest that I got is to open the terminal from Terminal menu, and in the terminal navigate to my python and execute IPython, but then I can't run some independent lines from my code using a shortcut (most precisely like the F9 in Spyder)

My Python is not in Windows path. I'm working with files from a disk E: and my python is on a disk C:.

Answer (score 0):

**No Work Reason:**

`"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}",` is the configuration of the default terminal. You can find out the terminal name was **powershell** or something others. But when you take the command of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`, the name of the terminal was the explicit name: `Python`.

**Impossible Reason:**

Unfortunately, the `Python` extension seems has not provided the configuration to modify the **cwd** when you take the command of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` while you can modify the **cwd** when you take the command of `Run Python File in Terminal`. As the IPython has no configuration to modify the **cwd** too, so it seems has not a suitable method to achieve your aim.

**Workaround:**

*Method1:* After you into the REPL mode, modify the **cwd** like this:

```
import os
os.chdir('/tmp')
```

*Method2:*

1. Change the configuration:  `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true`
2. Execute the command of `Run Python File in Terminal` first, in order to change the terminal path.
3. Execute the command of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`.

*Method3:*

1. Execute the command of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`.
2. Exit out and change the path of the terminal.
3. Run IPython again.

Comment: @alanTri [Respect executeInFileDir when 'Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6632)

Comment: Hello Steven. I was hoping for a definite solution, unfortunately there is only workarounds. I'm picking a mix of your suggested methods and mines. My workaround for now is:  `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true`, execute the "$PYTHONPATH -m IPython" in the terminal, configure a shortcut to CTRL + ENTER to "Run Selected Text In **Active Terminal**".